# Fetch extra data for large number of IDs

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a MySQL table containing information about objects. It looks like this:

```
+--------------+----+--------+-------+
| auto_incr_id | id |  type  | value |
+--------------+----+--------+-------+
|            1 |  1 | length |   105 |
|            2 |  1 | weight |    17 |
|            3 |  1 | price  |   104 |
|            4 |  2 | length |   111 |
|            5 |  2 | weight |    18 |
|            6 |  2 | price  |    87 |
+--------------+----+--------+-------+
```

I want to fetch the first x objects, sorted by length:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "length": 111,
    "weight": 18,
    "price": 87
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "length": 105,
    "weight": 17,
    "price": 104
}
```

Here's what I do to achieve this:
First, I fetch the ids:

```
$type = "length";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE type=? ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT ?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $type, $limit);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$result = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Next, I get the other values for each object that was fetched:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($result)) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT type, value FROM table WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $result[$i]['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result_2 = $stmt->get_result();
    $fetch = $result_2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $j = 0;
    while ($j < count($fetch))
    {
        $result[$i][$fetch[$j]['type']] = $fetch[$j]['value'];
        $j++;
    }
}
```

This works great to fetch for example the top 5 (`$limit = 5`), but now I have a use case where I want to have this information for the top 10k or more. This take too much time, probably because it needs to go through the while loop and execute a statement for every found ID.

So I'm looking for a way to reduce the execution time getting this data. Any ideas?

Comment: Do it INSIDE the database. Join your two queries.

Comment: @kainaw it is not that easy. EAV is always a pain to deal with

Comment: @kainaw not sure how that would work... could you elaborate a bit or give an example?

Comment: @YourCommonSense whould suggest a different database setup then? I've chosen this setup because it's unclear how many types there will be monitored, and not all objects will have the same types monitored.

Comment: @YourCommonSense whats possibly wrong with EAV (joke offcource)..... Topicstarter ideally you need to use the existing EAV table models to identify common object properties and create a table for it.. I also had to deal with this i build a EAV staging table and program and exported useable tables from it to be used in the main program.. When properties are added then offcource you need to rerun a rebuild script and change the main program aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue appears to be a lack of understanding about table joins. There is a wrong and a right way to do this. The wrong way is very easy to understand, so I will show it so it makes sense...

```
select id, type, value from table where id in (select id from table where type='length');
```

That obviously gets the type/value combination from every id that has a value for type='length'. But, you aren't doing it ALL in the database. You still have to sort and group everything outside the database. Let's assume you only have type='length', 'weight' and 'price'. I can create three tables on the fly for that, creating attributes of length, weight, and price...

```
select l.id, length, weight, price from
(select id, value as length from table where type='length') l
left outer join
(select id, value as weight from table where type='weight') w
on l.id=w.id
left outer join
(select id, value as price from table where type='price') p
on l.id=p.id
order by length
```

Now, you will get each attribute in a row, one row per id. The id field is not guaranteed to be unique here. If you have the same ID with more than one length, it will show up more than once in the results. But, I hope you can see how I took the obvious subquery and turned it into a join to do all the work inside the database.

NOTE: I fixed the ambiguity error and added "left outer" to include rows where weight and price do not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When trying your query in phpmyadmin, I get: `column id in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Fixed the above by using `s.id` instead of `id`, but I found another issue: the solution only seems to work when length, weight and price are present for a certain ID, while it should always give you data for all IDs, even if one or more of the types are missing.

Comment: You can use a left outer join instead of join to get nulls where something is not present.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for helping out! One more thing: can I use USE INDEX on all 4 selects? How would that work?

Comment: There is no reason you can't use "use index(id)" at the end of each of the inner queries. You can't use it in the outer query because there is no index That is a temporary table created just for this query. In the end, I don't expect it to speed up the query much. If anything, it will help sort the data quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Well at least you can always use a subquery

```
SELECT id, type, value FROM table 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE type=? ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT ?")
order by id
```

Comment: if the value column values for types are not unique i doubt this would work correctly as this `ORDER BY` then would be non deterministic as for `|  1 | length |   105 |` and `|  2 | length |   105 |` you can't predict which of these two records is "first" or "last" .. To be fair the topicstarter didn't mention annything about duplicated data like i said

Comment: It's indeed possible two different IDs have the same length. It's however not possible that the same ID has two values for length.

Comment: ok @binoculars then this query would work fine and the `ORDER BY` would be considered deterministic as the values are always unique..

Comment: @RaymondNijland so no need for an auto increment column as you mentioned before? Because I have one, I just didn't mention it for simplicity's sake.

Comment: no you don't have to add it then i removed that comment @binoculars i misread your first comment..

Comment: OK, so now I have `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, type, value FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE type=? ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT ?) order by id");` , but I get `Call to a member function bind_param() on bool` when I try to bind the params. Is there something wrong with my `prepare`?

Comment: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool means there something wrong with your query. you need at least use real values instead of those bogus names you used in the question. and test your queries in phpmyadmin first

Comment: Yes, I renamed the bogus names (and missed one the first time so always good to double check indeed...). I tried it in phpmyadmin and got: `This version of MariaDB doesn't support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`. I'm using `10.3.16-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution`

Comment: Too bad, but thanks anyway for the suggestion. Was hoping that updating MariaDB would be a quick fix but it appears that it's not supported in the newer versions either... back to square one.

Comment: @binoculars Still you could get all ids using array_column() and then use them all in a [single query with IN operator](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_statement_with_in_clause)